# Can not get Navigation Drawer in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd, buildozer

**Hello, I am using KIVY not KIVYMD to make a project.**
I have created a nice app but now, it is incomplete without a navigation drawer from the left side.
I any how want to create a side menu with some options in my app but when I import the navigation bar using the command:

```
from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.navigationdrawer'
```

Can you please tell me what is the reason? Is their any other way to create such a side panel? Please help.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [this](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/0.104.0/components/navigation-drawer/index.html). Here you'll see lots of different things to add in NavigationDrawer with great explanation.

Comment: My project is with kivy and I can't use kivymd.

Comment: Kivy doesn't have NavigationDrawer. Just Import "MDAPP" instead of "APP". You can't get  NavigationDrawer in Kivy. You have to use KivyMD. FYI you can use both KIVY and KIVYMD in your project.